# Is the Before handler in Nancy apps sensitive to code formatting?

Tags: asp.net, routes, nancy

I have a strange issue with the Before handler in a Nancy application (relatively new to this, so please bear with me). When the code in the Action of a Before filter is refactored it stops working, even though the code does exactly the same. This code in my Module works:

```
Get["/"] = parameters => "Hello World";

Get["/{name}"] = parameters => "Hello " + parameters.name;

Before += ctx =>
    {
        if (ctx.Parameters.name == "Harry")
        {
            return "Bugger off";
        }
        return null;
    };
```

This displays "Hello Mark" if I call it with the parameter Mark, and "Bugger off" with "Harry" as a parameter, and "Hello world" without parameters.
However if I change the Before filter definition to this (as suggested by Resharper):

```
    Before += ctx =>
    {
        return ctx.Parameters.name == "Harry" ? "Bugger off" : null;
    };
```

Or even:

```
    Before += ctx => ctx.Parameters.name == "Harry" ? "Bugger off" : null;
```

It works only when I supply the parameter "Harry", otherwise it doesn't return anything.
According to the docs, returning null from a Before Action causes the request handler to be called normally, but even though the above code should return null except when the parameter "Harry" is supplied, it seems the request handler isn't called.

Comment: I don't see how this can affect the outcome, especially the first change - it's just C# code. If you now change it back to the original full code, does it still work correctly?

Comment: No, Before does not depend on the shape of the code in the action. Before action are simply called by Nancy.

Comment: It is consistent, every time I try to use the second or third version it fails, when I change the code back to the first variant it works as expected.

Comment: Note: this was a test project, the code above is almost all the code in the entire project, it's the content of the constructor of the only module, which contains no other code besides the ctor.